# Adding an element with keypress event

Tags: javascript, html, events, keypress

So I'm just learning JavaScript and I'm trying to make a payment calculator for my church's daycare. I want a second div with class "child" (all the 'stuff' inside it) to be added to the div with id "children". I have it where a simple div is added with a key press but it won't add a third. How do I add more than one div and how do I add a div with all the 'stuff'? Code is below:

```
 <div id="input">
    <div id="children">
        <div class="child">
        <h2>Choose Child's Class</h2>
        <select id="primary" class="selector">
            <option value=" ">Select Class</option>
            <option value=200>Infants</option>
            <option value=175>Wobblers</option>
            <option value=175>Toddlers</option>
            <option value=165>PreSchool 3's</option>
            <option value=165>PreK 4's</option>
            <option value=75>Schooler Before &amp; After</option>
            <option value=40>Schooler Before Only</option>
            <option value=65>Schooler After Only</option>
            <option value=60>Schooler AFA Before &amp; After</option>
            <option value=20>Schooler AFA Before Only</option>
            <option value=30>Schooler AFA After Only</option>
            <option value=40>Part Time</option>
        </select>
        </div><!--closes child class div-->
   </div><!--closes children id dive-->

    <h3> Press any key on your keyboard to add another child</h3>
```

and the javaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $newChild=$('<div class="child">Testing</div>');
    $(document).keyup(function(){
        $newChild.appendTo($('#children'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So for starters this is how your javascript should look like so you can add many divs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', function(){
        var $newChild=$('<div class="child">Testing</div>');
        $newChild.appendTo($('#children'));
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', function(){
        var $newChild=$('<div class="child">Testing</div>'); 
        $('#children').append($newChild);
    });
});
```

You need to clarify the rest of your question why do you mean by stuff?

Comment: it's the right answer, but do you know why? (i'm not the OP) :)

Comment: The reason for this is because he declared the variable outside of the scope, the first time the variable is in scope however next time the event is triggered the variable will be out of scope and undefined.

Comment: I would think the keyup keeps appending the same object, replacing itself. In OPs code, there is only ever one newChild

Comment: Appending is adding to the object(DOM) not replacing, always to the bottom. http://api.jquery.com/appendto/ for reference

Comment: I would expect to see a clone(). When you access the same object, it is just moved around

Comment: Everytime the user presses a key the event is run, this creates a new variable 'newchild' that is appended to the children target. This changes the DOM, and keeps the changes. When the user triggers the event again the process is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery needs to be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var childHtml = "<div class='child'>Child</div>";
    $(document).keyup(function() {        
        $('#children').append(childHtml);
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ek922tz2/7/

Comment: Could be, really depends on the user's usage. keypress only accepts input characters, so arrows and such won't trigger it. I only went with 'keyup' because the OP was using it.

Comment: The issue with key press is that its repeated if you hold the key down causing issues with too many items being added by accident.

Comment: keypress, keydown, and keyup all will work. Just depends on how you want your code to function.